# python recursion function depth

Tags: python, sorting, recursion

This program sorts a list recursively using insertion sort...
Can someone please make me understand how 'isort' works recursively and how 'insert' runs even after 'isort' recursion, is isort recursion suspended until it has ran once completely?

```
def insertion(seq):
  isort(seq,len(seq))

def isort(seq,k):
  if k>1:
    isort(seq,k-1)
    insert(seq,k-1)

def insert(seq,k):
  pos=k
  while pos>0 and seq[pos]<seq[pos-1]:
    (seq[pos],seq[pos-1])=(seq[pos-1],seq[pos])
    pos=pos-1
```

Comment: Not sure if this explains it, but related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROalU379l3U

Comment: Hmm, this code is indeed insertion sort, but an assignment operation is needlessly replaced by a swap.

Comment: yea its needless , its just an recursion example

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `isort(seq, k)`

The function makes sure that the last k elements are sorted

```
def isort(seq,k):
  if k>1:
    isort(seq,k-1)  
    // seq[k-1:] is sorted

    insert(seq,k-1)
    // the k'th item is now inserted in the correct place,
    // so seq[k:] is sorted
```

for `k=len(seq)`, `seq[k:]` is trivially sorted (it's an empty list)
and the recursion decreases `k` by 1 in each step, sorting seq from tail to head

Comment: correct i understand that it sorts list from tail to head  ,but what i cant understand is how 'insert' function is being called even when 'isort' recursively reduces k to 0 or 1 and the if condition is not met,and   sorry for being so stupid am a newbie in programming

Comment: I think the problem is that you don't understand python syntax: the two rows after the if are inside the if, because they are indented. so both run every time

Comment: OK bear with me one last question, so when ever the if condition is met it first calls 'isort' and then 'insert' OR they are called together. In my understanding insert  won't run unless recursive 'isort' call   has finished execution completely.

Comment: They are called one after the other. It looks like isort {isort {isort .... {isort insert} insert} insert}. ... }insert